# Not getting the output from shell script in Gitlab CI

Tags: shell, gitlab

I have set up a gitlab runner on my windows. I have a `build.sh` script in which I am just echoing "Hello world". I have provided these lines in my `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - ./build.sh
```

The runner executes this job but does not print the echo command which I have mentioned in the `build.sh` file. But if I changed the extension to `.bat` it works and shows me the output. The `gitlab-runner` is set up for shell. What can be the possible reason? or I am missing something?

Answer (score 5):

GitLab will output for anything that ends up written to STDOUT or STDERR. It's hard to say what's happening without seeing your whole script, but I imagine somehow you're not actually echoing to STDOUT. This is why the output isn't ending up in the CI output.

To test this I created a test project on GitLab.com. One difference in my test is my CI YAML script command was `sh build.sh`. This is because the script wasn't executable so it couldn't be executed with `./build.sh`.

**`builds.sh` file:**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "This is output from build.sh"
```

**`.gitlab-ci.yml` file:**

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - sh build.sh
```

**The build output:**

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.3.0-rc1 (afb9fab4)
  on docker-auto-scale 72989761
...
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/dblessing/ci-output-test/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out cfe8a4ee as master...

Skipping Git submodules setup

$ sh build.sh
This is output from build.sh
Job succeeded
```

Comment: Is it possible in gitlab CI to print every shell command that is being executed, like Jenkins does?

Comment: GitLab will show all commands that are specified within the `.gitlab-ci.yml` directly. This is shown as `$ sh build.sh` in the output example above. GitLab will not show what's going on within a given script file, though. Although I don't know for sure, I would be surprised in Jenkins does, either. A script could choose to manually print commands or output as relevant, and GitLab will show those in the build trace.